# Git db.sqlite and wsgi.py file keep reverting on pull

Tags: django, git, ubuntu-18.04, wagtail

I have a python/django/wagtail project that I built locally using db.sqlite3. I did an initial push with everything to github, and then pulled it to my server. I made a change to the wsgi file and did some work in the cms which updated the database.

I made some changes locally. I changed my .gitignore to exclude db.sqlite3 and wsgi.py. `git add .`, `git commit`, `git push origin master`. then, on the server, `sudo git pull origin master`. db.sqlite3 reverts back to before I made the cms changes and the wsgi.py reverts back to pointing to my dev settings.

I made the changes back to the cms but now I need to do another update when I have made even more cms changes and I do not want to overwrite the database again. wsgi.py is a small fix but still. My .gitignore

```
# Created by https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/django
# Edit at https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore?templates=django

### Django ###
*.log
*.pot
*.pyc
__pycache__/
local_settings.py
db.sqlite3
db.sqlite3-journal
media
wsgi.py

# If your build process includes running collectstatic, then you probably don't need or want to include staticfiles/
# in your Git repository. Update and uncomment the following line accordingly.
# <django-project-name>/staticfiles/

### Django.Python Stack ###
# Byte-compiled / optimized / DLL files
*.py[cod]
*$py.class

# C extensions
*.so

# Distribution / packaging
.Python
build/
develop-eggs/
dist/
downloads/
eggs/
.eggs/
lib/
lib64/
parts/
sdist/
var/
wheels/
pip-wheel-metadata/
share/python-wheels/
*.egg-info/
.installed.cfg
*.egg
MANIFEST

# PyInstaller
#  Usually these files are written by a python script from a template
#  before PyInstaller builds the exe, so as to inject date/other infos into it.
*.manifest
*.spec

# Installer logs
pip-log.txt
pip-delete-this-directory.txt

# Unit test / coverage reports
htmlcov/
.tox/
.nox/
.coverage
.coverage.*
.cache
nosetests.xml
coverage.xml
*.cover
*.py,cover
.hypothesis/
.pytest_cache/
pytestdebug.log

# Translations
*.mo

# Django stuff:

# Flask stuff:
instance/
.webassets-cache

# Scrapy stuff:
.scrapy

# Sphinx documentation
docs/_build/
doc/_build/

# PyBuilder
target/

# Jupyter Notebook
.ipynb_checkpoints

# IPython
profile_default/
ipython_config.py

# pyenv
.python-version

# pipenv
#   According to pypa/pipenv#598, it is recommended to include Pipfile.lock in version control.
#   However, in case of collaboration, if having platform-specific dependencies or dependencies
#   having no cross-platform support, pipenv may install dependencies that don't work, or not
#   install all needed dependencies.
#Pipfile.lock

# PEP 582; used by e.g. github.com/David-OConnor/pyflow
__pypackages__/

# Celery stuff
celerybeat-schedule
celerybeat.pid

# SageMath parsed files
*.sage.py

# Environments
#.env
.venv
env/
venv/
ENV/
env.bak/
venv.bak/
wow/

# Spyder project settings
.spyderproject
.spyproject

# Rope project settings
.ropeproject

# mkdocs documentation
/site

# mypy
.mypy_cache/
.dmypy.json
dmypy.json

# Pyre type checker
.pyre/

# pytype static type analyzer
.pytype/

# End of https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/django
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a line to `.gitignore` does not stop that file from being tracked by git - it just means that changes to it won't show up in `git status` / `git diff` and similar. To remove it from git, you need to run `git rm name-of-file` . However, this will also delete the actual file, so to avoid losing data, the best approach is:

- make a copy of db.sqlite3
- `git rm db.sqlite3`
- move your copy of the file back to the original filename
- commit the change to git

Then, on your live server:

- make a copy of db.sqlite3
- `git pull`
- move your copy of the file back to the original filename